# How get list submodules from git bare repo without create working tree?

Tags: git, libgit2, pygit2

How get list submodules in git bare repo without create working tree?

(with low level library libgit2 or git console)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the information is stored in `.gitmodules` at the root of the repo, the simplest way is to inspect that file without checking it out:

```
git show HEAD:.gitmodules
```

I just tested, and this command works from within a bare repo, just as it would from a regular sandbox.